# How to clear, remove, or reset HTML5 form validation state after "setCustomValidity("...");"?

Tags: javascript, forms, html, validation

How to clear, remove, or reset HTML5 form validation state after `setCustomValidity("...");`?

Setting an empty string, `setCustomValidity("");`, in Firefox and Chrome closes the form validation error message. I do not want to close the form validation error message. I want to reset the validation state so that the next answer can be checked and also to keep the displayed validation error message. If the validation state is not reset, then even the next, correct answer will incorrectly show a validation error message.

---

So somehow, "clear" means "close"?

> If the argument is the empty string, clears the custom error.

http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#the-constraint-validation-api

---

Here is a validation test case:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>Validation test case</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="testForm">
            <input type="text" id="answer" pattern="[A-Za-z]+" autofocus required/>
            <input type="submit" value="OK"/>
        </form>

        <script>
            /*jslint browser: true, vars: true, white: true, maxerr: 50, indent: 4 */
            (function ()
            {
                "use strict";

                var form = null;
                var answer = null;

                var isCorrectAnswer = function (value)
                {
                    return (value === "a");
                };

                var closeValidation = function (element)
                {
                    // Close the form validation error message if displayed.
                    element.blur();
                    element.focus();
                };

                var validateForm = function (event)
                {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    event.stopPropagation();

                    var isValidForm = event.target.checkValidity();
                    if (isValidForm)
                    {
                        if (isCorrectAnswer(answer.value))
                        {
                            form.reset();
                            closeValidation(answer);

                            console.log("Correct answer.");
                            alert("Correct answer.");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            console.log("Incorrect answer.");
                            answer.setCustomValidity("Incorrect answer.");
                            answer.checkValidity();
                            //answer.setCustomValidity("");
                        }
                    }
                };

                window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function ()
                {
                    form = document.getElementById("testForm");
                    answer = document.getElementById("answer");

                    form.addEventListener("submit", validateForm, false);
                }, false);
            }());
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Type an incorrect answer, any letters(s) but "a", and press Enter.
Type the correct answer "a", and press Enter.

Without changes to the test case, the behavior is the same in Opera, Firefox, and Chrome (except the Chrome bugs). The validation error message persists regardless if the answer is correct or incorrect.

Now, after `answer.setCustomValidity("");` is uncommented, Opera clears the custom validation error but does not close the validation error message, which is what I expect. On the other hand, Firefox and Chrome both clear the custom validation error and close the validation error message (bug?).

---

**BUG:** Chrome doesn't "checkValidity()" when first invoked.

In Chrome, `answer.checkValidity();` doesn't show the validation message after the first submit. Subsequent submits show the validation error message.

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=95970

**BUG:** In Chrome, the validation error message is blanked but not closed when the input is changed.

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=95973

---

Opera 11.51 Build 1087

Firefox 6.0.2

Google Chrome 13.0.782.220 m

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A custom validation message is not shown if setCustomValidity() is called in 'submit' event handler.

@tkent:

> I confirmed Opera 11.50 worked as your expectation, but Firefox 6 and
>   Chrome 14 didn't.
>
> However, Chrome's behavior is correct according to the standard.
>
> http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#form-submission-algorithm
>
> > 5. If the submitted from submit() method flag is not set, and the
> >        submitter element's no-validate state is false, then interactively
> >        validate the constraints of form and examine the result: if the result
> >        is negative (the constraint validation concluded that there were
> >        invalid fields and probably informed the user of this) then abort
> >        these steps.
> > 6. If the submitted from submit() method flag is not set, then fire
> >        a simple event that is cancelable named submit, at form. If the
> >        event's default action is prevented (i.e. if the event is canceled)
> >        then abort these steps. Otherwise, continue (effectively the default
> >        action is to perform the submission).
>
> Browsers must invoke the interactive validation BEFORE 'submit' event
>   is fired. You need to call setCustomValidity() before 'submit' event
>   if you want a browser to show a validation message.  Opera seems to
>   handle these steps in incorrect order. Note that checkValidity() in
>   your code has no effect anyway.  checkValidity() never shows a
>   validation message.

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=95970

---

[Bug 11287] New: 'setCustomValidity' call in  element should use 'oninput' event...

@Nick:

> 'setCustomValidity' call in  element should use 'oninput'
>   event...

http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-html/2010Nov/0186.html

---

Re: [whatwg] Form element invalid message

@Mounir Lamouri:

> So, what you do is making the element valid in the invalid event which
>   is too late. After the invalid event, Firefox tries to show the UI
>   using the validationMessage which return the empty string when the
>   form is valid. You should cancel the event if you want to have no UI
>   at all but still cancel the submission. You should use
>   *onchange/oninput* (emphasis added) to change the validity state if you want the form to
>   be submitted.

http://www.mail-archive.com/whatwg@lists.whatwg.org/msg23762.html

---

The fix is to validate the input with the "input" event handler instead of the "submit" event handler.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>Validation test case</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="testForm">
            <input type="text" id="answer" pattern="[A-Za-z]+" autofocus required/>
            <input type="submit" value="OK"/>
        </form>

        <script>
            /*jslint browser: true, vars: true, white: true, maxerr: 50, indent: 4 */
            (function (console)
            {
                "use strict";

                var form = null;
                var answer = null;

                var isCorrectAnswer = function (value)
                {
                    return (value === "a");
                };

                var closeValidation = function (element)
                {
                    // Close the form validation error message if displayed.
                    element.blur();
                    element.focus();
                };

                var validateForm = function (event)
                {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    event.stopPropagation();

                    var isValidForm = event.target.checkValidity();
                    if (isValidForm)
                    {
                        console.log("Correct answer.");
                        closeValidation(answer);
                        form.reset();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        console.log("Incorrect answer.");
                    }
                };

                window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function ()
                {
                    form = document.getElementById("testForm");
                    answer = document.getElementById("answer");

                    form.addEventListener("submit", validateForm, false);
                    answer.addEventListener("input", function ()
                    {
                        // Only show custom form validation error message if the value matches the pattern.
                        if (answer.value.match(new RegExp(answer.getAttribute("pattern"))))
                        {
                            answer.setCustomValidity(isCorrectAnswer(answer.value) ? "" : "Incorrect answer.");
                        }
                    }, false);
                }, false);
            }(window.console));
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: tl;dr: Don't use setCustomValidity in the 'submit' event. It is meant to be set before the 'submit' event such as in the 'input' or 'change' event.

Comment: But to have consistent user experience, I want ability to tell the user there is something wrong with a specific field (e.g. no such user), with the same UI as the rest of my form.

Comment: So the answer is basically `setCustomValidity('')`: setting a blank string cancels the validation.

Comment: i just hit this... and it seems to work in chrome and safari but surprisingly not firefox... i enter bad string.. validation (oninput or onchange) sets the validation message (custom) and everything is well with the world. Then i go to correct it, and its valid email and still shows the message. Another issue I found which happens in any browser it seems (for email).. is that test@test passes  ... with out the suffix .com or whatever... whats up with that?

Comment: @carinlynchin I had the same issue as you mentioned, I fixed it with this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71843811/712700

Answer (score -3):

Just use `.reset()` if you wish to reset the entire form:

```
form_object.reset();

document.getElementById('form_63').reset();

document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].reset();
```