# How to reset validation after the form is submitted with AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, forms

I have a form validated with html5 validation then submitted with AJAX, then the inputs fields are reset, it's working.

My problem is that after a valid submission, message was sent, inputs are cleared, but the html5 validation still outlines my empty fields as incorrect fields.

HTML:

```
 <form method="post" action="mailer.php" class="contact-form" id="cform">
     <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required />
     <input type="text" name="phone"  placeholder="Phone" required />                       
     <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required />                       
     <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
     <input type="submit" class="submit-btn" id="submit-btn" value="Send your message" />
     <div id="success"></div>
 </form>
```

JQUERY:

```
 $('#submit-btn').click(function(){
     if($("#cform")[0].checkValidity()) {

         $.post("mailer.php", $("#cform").serialize(),  function(response) {
             $('#success').html(response);
             $("#cform")[0].reset();
         });
         return false;

     } else console.log("invalid form");
 });
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/ will do it

Answer (score 1):

You need to stop the default submit behavior.

```
 $('#submit-btn').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     // ...
 }
```

Or you could just use `type="button"` instead of `type="submit"`.

Comment: that's what the return false did

Comment: This disabled the html5 validation completely.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest you use the submit event

If you are using the new HTML5 validation (required for example) your .reset() should work.

It works for me [<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/cxhQK/)

```
$(function() {
  $('#cform').on("submit",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();  
    if($("#cform")[0].checkValidity()) {
      $.post("/echo/json/", $("#cform").serialize(),function(response) {
        $('#success').html(response);
        $("#cform")[0].reset();
      });
     }
     else window.console &&  console.log("invalid form");
   });
 });
```

If not, try focus and blur each field to tell the validator the fields are ok,

see [How to clear, remove, or reset HTML5 form validation state after "setCustomValidity("...");"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357192/how-to-clear-remove-or-reset-html5-form-validation-state-after-setcustomvalid)

If you use the [jQUery validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation) you need to do a [resetForm()](http://jqueryvalidation.org/Validator.resetForm)

Comment: Tried this, but unfortunately didn't worked. The form fields is still outlined with red after the form is successfully submitted and the fields are cleared.

Comment: Thanks for your kindness and for reconstructing my issue. My site exactly works like your demo jsfiddle, after submitting the message the fields are shown as error fields. Btw if this is so complicated i may consider using a validation plugin :)