# .setCustomValidity; Will Not Reset After Triggering

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I'm trying test if the user enters the same password twice.

However once `.setCustomValidity` is triggered it will not reset to valid if valid input is entered and submit is pressed.

Here is a link to my JSFIDDLE [link](http://jsfiddle.net/HKw9w/).
JSFIDDLE shows an error that I cant make out.

here is my HTML:

```
<p id="demo">&nbsp;   </p>
<table>

<form onsubmit="validateInput(); return false"  method=post >
<tr>
    <td>Password</td>
          <td><input Id="Pass" name="Pass" type="password" required 
              placeholder="Secret" ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
   <td>Retype Password</td>
          <td><input Id="PassRe" name="PassRe" type="password" required 
               placeholder="Secret" ></td>
<tr>
     <td></td>

     <td>
         <input type="submit" class="Button" value="Submit">
         <input type="reset"  class="Button" value="Clear" name="ResetBtn">
     </td>
</tr>

</form>
</table>
```

The two inputs are Pass and PassRe by their given Id's.

The JS tests if the two inputs are equal to one another.

If they are not equal the script sets the .setCustomValidity and the `demo` text to show the error.

(Or at last that is what I want it to do.)

And my JS

```
function validateInput() {  

 var Pass1 = document.getElementById("Pass").value;
 var Pass2 = document.getElementById("PassRe").value;

if(Pass1 == Pass2){

      document.getElementById("PassRe").setCustomValidity('');                
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=  ('');     

            }else{
      document.getElementById("PassRe").setCustomValidity('The passwords dont match');
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=  ('The passwords dont match');                      

};
}
```

Comment: The jsfiddle does not run `validateInput` because it is defined as a local function. This is caused by the use of the “onLoad” option. Here’s working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7GjvL/

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela  Thanks but,it still is not resetting after an invalid input is entered. What did you have to change to make the JS load?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357192/how-to-clear-remove-or-reset-html5-form-validation-state-after-setcustomvalid

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I see what was changed the JSFIDDLE option. I will look at that duplicate thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[Problem solved in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357192/how-to-clear-remove-or-reset-html5-form-validation-state-after-setcustomvalid)

Chrome handles `.setCustomValidity` in a odd way. 
And because the `.setCustomValidity` is handled by the browser the issue is browser dependent. 
Switched to full JS validation and removed parts that used  `.setCustomValidity` to fix problem.

[JSFIDDLE Example](http://jsfiddle.net/qQE8b/)