# How to remove "Please match the requested format"

Tags: javascript, html

How do I change **"Please match the required format"** with **"Not valid"**

I've Looked all over the Stackoverflow couldn't find anything that help it may be a duplicate but please help me!

If I type **'asd'** in the field, then press **GO**, and then continue to type the message *"Please match the required format"* will appear

I don't want messy code, I want it to be in the html tags if possible!

```html
<form id="banner-message">
    <input value=""
    name="email" 
    id="inputEmail"
    class="form-control"
    placeholder="email"
    required="" 
    autofocus=""  
    oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Not Valid')"                                               oninput="setCustomValidity('')"
    pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$">

    <button class="btn btn-lg  btn-block" type="submit">Go</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks but I Did exactly what is written there and i could not managed it to work

Comment: Yeeah but when i continue to type the message shows

Comment: I you type per example 'asd' then press 'enter' and then continue to type  it will say "Please match the required format"

Comment: @KostadinSlavov Which the browser you're using?

Comment: Chromium  and Firefox

Comment: does not seem to be relevant anymore..? I am not seeing the prompt, only the "Not Valid" as expected

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to use `onchange` and  `this.setCustomValidity`

```html
  <form id="banner-message">
      <input value="" 
      name="email" 
      id="inputEmail"
      class="form-control"
      placeholder="email"
      required=""
      autofocus="" 
      oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Not Valid')"
      onchange="try{setCustomValidity('')}catch(e){}"
      oninput="setCustomValidity(' ')"
      pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$">

      <button class="btn btn-lg  btn-block" type="submit">Go</button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

```html
<form id="banner-message">
    <input value=""
    name="email" 
    id="inputEmail"
    class="form-control"
    placeholder="email"
    required="" 
    autofocus=""  
    oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Not Valid')"                                               oninput="setCustomValidity('')"
    pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$">

    <button class="btn btn-lg  btn-block" type="submit">Go</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also just set the `title` attribute:

```html
<form id="banner-message">
    <input value=""
    placeholder="email"
    required="" 
    title="Not Valid"
    pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$">

    <button class="btn btn-lg  btn-block" type="submit">Go</button>
</form>
```

Comment: While it works in Chrome/Firefox, it doesn't work in Safari.

Answer (score 0):

Also pay attention to add `oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')"` to input tag. Because if you don't, you may get a situation where warning messages are mixed.*(One input tag's warning message appears for another input tag)*

Answer (score -1):

The answer from Hyyan Abo Fakher kind of works, however it's buggy because we set the "customError" validity state by using setCustomValidity, this causes a lot of false positive validations.

Instead of using oninvalid, we should just use onChange and also check the Validity State for errors we are expecting and ignore customError. This code is for React:

```
<input
  ...
  onChange={event => {
    const target = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
    if (target?.validity?.patternMismatch) {
      target?.setCustomValidity(customInputError);
    } else {
      target?.setCustomValidity('');
    }}
```

Here I am only setting my custom error message when I see the "patternMismatch" validity state. If you would like to check all states then check for all of them except `target?.validity?.customError` as it's a false positive (set by our setCustomValidity call).