# oninvalid setCustomValidity Field will not validate after showing custom error message

Tags: javascript, html

When using the built in HTML5 form validation, I changed the error message that appears, but when the field is fixed, then error message keeps coming back and can not get the field to validate no matter what I do.

If the correct data is entered in the field initally, then it validates fine and the form will submit and continue.

But if I enter invalid data, then the custom error message will correctly show up on the field the first time, but even after the data is corrected, the error message will keep coming up everytime and prevent submission of form.

In this example code I am using a text input with pattern attribute to get a floating point number and a number input to get an integer.

```
<form>

Enter floating point nnumber: 
<input type='text' pattern='[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+' id='float-only' name='float-only' value=''>

Enter integer number: 
<input type='number' id='int-only' name='int-only' min='0' step='1' value=''>

</form>

<script>

document.getElementById('float-only').oninvalid = function(event) { event.target.setCustomValidity('Please enter valid FLOATING POINT number.'); }

document.getElementById('int-only').oninvalid = function(event) { event.target.setCustomValidity('Please enter valid INTEGER.'); }

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I posted a previous answer which I thought was working, but it turned out it did not, so I deleted it ... this one works:

The issue is that the custom validity error message needs to be reset to empty/blank or it will always not validate regardless of the data in the field, so you need to change it back to blank/empty ( so set = '' ).

I use `oninvalid` to set the custom error message, and then use `onchange` to set the message back to default (empty), and then when the form is checked again it will correctly submit if data was corrected, or it will set the custom validity error message again if there is problem.

So something like this:

```
<form>

Enter floating point nnumber: 
<input type='text' pattern='[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+' oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter valid FLOATING POINT number.')" onchange="this.setCustomValidity('')" id='float-only' name='float-only' value=''>

Enter integer number: 
<input type='number' oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter valid INTEGER.')" onchange="this.setCustomValidity('')" id='int-only' name='int-only' min='0' step='1' value=''>

</form>
```

Comment: This didn't quite work for me, I have an answer with a solution that worked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71843811/712700

Comment: it doesn't work if the validity issue is caused by 'required'. in such case onchange will not run, and validity message will not be cleared