# Error displaying validation message with .setCustomValidity()

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with the following code.

When I enter an invalid value it works, but if I do not remove the focus from the input and keep entering numbers, the invalid message is repeated

```js
        function cargar(){
            let boton=document.getElementById("boton");
            boton.addEventListener("click",comprobar);
        }

        function comprobar(elEvent){
            let valor=document.getElementById("valor");
            let patron=/^[0-9]{3}/;
            if(patron.test(valor.value)){
                valor.setCustomValidity("");
            }else{
                valor.setCustomValidity("Valor incorrecto");
            }
        }

        addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",cargar,false);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ej77</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="">
        <label for="valor">Valor: 
            <input type="text" name="valor" id="valor">
        </label>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Comprobar" id="boton">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Example:

[image]

Comment: You check it when you press the button. Try to add event listener to `valor` field's `onchange` event to verify

Comment: Have you check this answer ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357192/how-to-clear-remove-or-reset-html5-form-validation-state-after-setcustomvalid