# Required field is filled, but still shows tooltip

Tags: html, laravel-blade

I have a registration form that submits without a problem when everything is
filled correctly from the start.
When I leave open a required field, I of course get a "please fill out this field" tooltip from my browser, and cannot submit the form.
When I then fill in this field, and try to submit again, I still get that tooltip on that same field. The error disappears after a simple refresh.
However, it is only present on the `type="text"` inputs. I cannot replicate the error on the password field, and the terms checkbox, both of which are also required.

I tried `$('input[name="firstname"]').val();` in the console, and it yields the value, so the DOM "knows" the field is filled...

The form is written in Blade, as part of a Laravel project:

```
<form id="edit-form" action="{{route('register',compact('locale'))}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <label for="firstname">
        <span>@lang('register.firstname')*</span>
        <input name="firstname" type="text" class="required form-control" required value="{{ old('firstname') }}">
    </label>
    <label for="lastname">
        <span>@lang('register.lastname')*</span>
        <input name="lastname" type="text" class="required form-control" required value="{{ old('lastname') }}">
    </label>
    <label for="email">
        <span>@lang('register.email')*</span>
        <input name="email" type="email" class="required form-control" required value="{{ old('email') }}">
    </label>
    <label for="password">
        <span>@lang('register.password')*</span>
        <input name="password" type="password" class="required form-control" required value="{{ old('password') }}">
    </label>
    <label for="password_confirmation">
        <span>@lang('register.password_confirmation')*</span>
        <input name="password_confirmation" type="password" class="required form-control" required value="{{ old('password_confirmation') }}">
    </label>
    <label for="company">
        <span>@lang('register.company')*</span>
        <input name="company" type="text" class="required form-control" required value="{{ old('company') }}">
    </label>
    <label class="chk--normal" for="terms">
        <input {{ old('terms') == 'agreed' ? 'checked' : '' }} type="checkbox" name="terms" value="1" required>
        <span> @lang('register.terms')*</span>
    </label>
    <br>
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="{{env('RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY')}}"></div>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">
        @svg('solid/check')
        <span>@lang('register.register')</span>
    </button>
</form>
```

I have tried removing the prefilled value attribute, but that changed nothing.
I also tried on multiple browsers (Chrome, Opera, Firefox), the issue is global.

=================

**EDIT**

Turns out there was a piece of script in my template (added by a former colleague) that translated the tooltip, based on the selected language (to override the browser's language)

```
<script>
    // Add HTML5 validation messages
    $(function () {
        $('input[type="text"], input[type="email"], input[type="tel"], textarea')
            .toArray().forEach(function (input) {

            input.addEventListener('invalid', function (event) {
                input.setCustomValidity('@lang('content.input_invalid')');
            });
            input.addEventListener('valid', function (event) {
                input.setCustomValidity('');
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I added the solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION

I added this to the script, which solved my issue. With thanks to [How to clear, remove, or reset HTML5 form validation state after "setCustomValidity("...");"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357192/how-to-clear-remove-or-reset-html5-form-validation-state-after-setcustomvalid)

```
input.addEventListener('input', function (event) {
    input.setCustomValidity('');
});
```